# How can I insert a value based on a cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

How can I tell VBA to select whatever is in A9, use the value in A9 (which is B5), then go to B5 and insert a value 22 (which is in B9).

[image]

The output should look something like this:

[image]

22 value inserted in B5. Is there a way I can do this using excel formula or VBA programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do something like this:

```
Sub asd()

    Dim d 

    d = [A9].Value

    Range(d) = [A9].Offset(0, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: if I want to get whatever is in A9 & A10 and place 22 in A9 & A10 do I just make another method like sub asd2() but this time for A10?

Comment: sorry did not follow you, can you rephrase please?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub DoIt1()
    Range(Range("A9")).Value = Range("B9").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: this won't add 22 number in B5 cell?, I want the program to use B5 which  is in A9 -> go to B5 and insert a value 22

Comment: @pnuts What did I miss?

Comment: @user3561813 I have one more question, what if A9 had no value, how can I write a vba so that if there is something in A9 take whatever is in B9 and insert it in A9, but if there is nothing in A9 then don't do anything?

Comment: @user3812613 I'm leaving another answer below with the response to this question (easier than trying to add the answer in a comment).

Answer (score 1):

Try this module:

```
sub copy_paste_fun()

    dim new_range as string
    new_range = range("A9").value

    dim new_value as double
    new_value = range("B9").value

    range(new_range) = new_value
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To refer to value in A9 you can use

```
Range("A9").select
```

To refer to value in adjacent B column you can use Offset function.

```
Range("A9").Offset(0, 1).Select
```

But I feel there is no need of using offset function too:

You can use:

```
Range(Range("A9")).Value = Range("B9").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to a question in the comments (checking if the cell has a Range in its contents first):

```
Sub DoDoDo()
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = Range(Range("A9").Value)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Value = 99
    Else
        'Do Nothing or Catch the error
    End If
End Sub
```